# Should Windows 7 home premium have chgport?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

So I have a fresh install of 64 bit Windows home premium - straight from a hologramed retail disk. I cannot use the chgport command line utility - it is not recognized.

Is this correct behaviour for this version of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should (see more [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/tp/command-prompt-commands-p1.02.htm)).

Comment: Hmm - seems like I may genuinely be missing it - although this makes no sense for a fresh install. Going to look around.